# Creating a permalink to first_tag archive?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, tags

I am  trying to create a link to the archive of the first tag in the current post.  I wonder how I can make this is possible.

I've wanted something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/tags/first_tag_ofmypost"> Linked Title </a>
```

The instructions have to be inside an "if"

```
<?php 
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if (has_tag( 'xtag' )) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo ?????????????? ?>"> Linked Title</a>
```

The `???????` is for the missing instruction to call the permalink of my tag.  I've been trying with `get_tag_link($tag->term_id)` but cant make it work.

Comment: why not just try and check once

Comment: Solved! I find the answer here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49056/how-to-get-the-first-tag-of-a-post-as-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Try this : ( not tested )

```
...

if (has_tag( 'xtag' )) { 

    $tag  = get_term_by('name', 'name_of_your_tag', 'type_of_your_tag'); // you should indicate the type of your xtag tag

?>

<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag['term_id']); ?>">Linked Title</a>

<?php } ?>

...
```

EDIT

Try this :

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

for($i = 0; $i<count($tags); $i++){

    $tag = $tags[$i];

    if($tag['name'] == 'name_of_you_tag'){

        echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag['term_id']).'">Linked Title</a>';
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: tks but I get the same result, the link of the current post; but I try to get the link of the first tag archive

Comment: can you do a `var_dump` of `$tag` ?

Comment: do a `var_dump` and copy the result here.

Comment: ok i add:
echo var_dump($tag)."<br>";
that after my href line.

I get:
bool(false)

Comment: Ok, I dont know the type of your `xtag`, it's a category, custom tax, .. you should change the `get_term_by` 3rd param according to that. Take a look here, It can help you to understand : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Examples.

Comment: xtag is an especific tag, so i figured the term "post_tag" should be ok, but its not working, tks

Comment: You should be sure about the type of your tag, and of course when  you call the ` get_term_by ` function you should put the real name of your tag.

Comment: aa ok, i tried
$tag = get_term_by('name', 'xtag', 'post_tag');
but that break my php.
I dont know, but i think the problem could be because i have 
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
just before my "if"

Comment: tks bro, but that broke my code, i get a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in single.php on line X

Comment: tks i found the answer now, tks anyway akmozo u help me to understand the code too, sallem maleikum